# hostname cannot resolved during installation of IBM private cloud ce

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I installed IBM-Cloud-private-ce by following the guide https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_1.2.0/installing/install_containers_CE.html
But after I ran docker run -e LICENSE=accept --net=host   -t -v "$(pwd)":/installer/cluster   ibmcom/cfc-installer:1.2.0 install, I got the following error messages

```
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/check/tasks/main.yaml:78
fatal: [a.b.c.d] => Hostname should be resolved to a valid IP address
fatal: [a.b.c.e] => Hostname should be resolved to a valid IP address
```

I put the ip address as [a.b.c.d] just for confidential. Actually they are numbers here. These IP address are reachable. 
By checking the ansible file, I noticed the following code

```
- name: Checking Hostname is resolvable
  shell: ping -c 1 $(hostname) | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2;exit}'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: ip_out

- name: Validating Hostname is resolvable
  fail: msg="Hostname should be resolved to a valid IP address"
  when: ip_out.stdout in ['', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.1.1']
```

I found I cannot ping in the container as the image hasn't ping in it.
Is this the reason why I got the message? I appreciate if anyone could help on it.

Updated the question. Thanks @SBERENS

I tried on the 2.1.0 version and met the same issue: (for confidential reason, I used a.b.c.d as the IP address, actually the IP address are reachable)

My /etc/hosts is like the following:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       e1.xx.yy.com e1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
#puppet:
a.b.c.a puppet.xx.yy.com puppet

a.b.c.d     e1.xx.yy.com e1
a.b.c.e e2.xx.yy.com e2
```

The cluster/hosts is like:

```
[master]
a.b.c.d

[worker]
a.b.c.e

[proxy]
a.b.c.e
#[management]
#4.4.4.4
```

Comment: Remove e1 from /etc/hosts also set to true loopback dns resolve to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue will occur in either 1.2 or 2.1.

The error is that the hostname `e1.xx.yy.com` resolves to `a.b.c.d` and `127.0.1.1`. When this happens, the installer is enforcing the resolved IP to be something which is externally routable.

Is there a reason why you have the machine hostname defined on the local address in addition to a separate network IP?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details! I got the VM from cloud service, it was predefined by default.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted seems to be for older 1.2 level.

Please check that you are following the correct most updated installation instructions. 
Latest version ICP 2.1 - CE are here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/installing/install_ce.html

Can you please post your /etc/hosts file and the cluster/hosts file contents?

Comment: Thanks. @sberens, I followed the guide of 2.1.0 and still met this issue. I updated the question my hosts file. Please could you have a check?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest removal of the line:

> 127.0.1.1       e1.xx.yy.com e1

from /etc/hosts. This can cause DNS confusion esp on Ubuntu.